# how to validate a XML file that I have in my project folder using karate

Tags: karate

I am able to validate XML responses that I receive from API as such. But unable to use the XML file which is in my project folder for validation.

Is there any syntax in Karate to read the XML file??  Maybe since I am reading it as a string and not as XML, the XPath expressions are failing. Could anyone please help me to resolve this?

```
Scenario:   JMS Test

   Given def response = karate.readAsString('expected.xml')
   Then match //Envelope/Body/CalculateRetailBasketTotal/header[1]/messageID == 'ECOMM CRB Service test'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, don't read it as a string. Read the docs, Karate has native XML support: https://github.com/intuit/karate#reading-files

So this should work:

```
Given def response = karate.read('expected.xml')
Then match //Envelope/Body/CalculateRetailBasketTotal/header[1]/messageID == 'ECOMM CRB Service test'
```

Comment: Thanks. But have tried that as well. If I try karate.read, I am getting 'javascript evaluation failed: karate.read('expected.xml'), javascript evaluation failed: error'

Comment: @DeepakPrabhu then there must be something wrong with your XML file. with the lack of info you have provided, the only option for you is to follow this process, all the best: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue